# how to fill textfield with database value in Yii?

Tags: php, yii, textfield

I want to fill one of the textfields with a value from a database.

Commonly, this code was recommended:

```
<div class="row">
  <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'field1'); ?>
  <?php echo Model1::model()->FindByPk($model->id)->field1;?>
  <?php echo $form->error($model,'field1'); ?>
</div>
```

But, the one I'm searching is the value is filled into textfield at the form.

Could anyone help me? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo Chtml::textField('txtFieldName', Model1::model()->FindByPk($model->id)->field1); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [Yii's Blog Demo](http://www.yiiframework.com/demos/blog/)? It is also available in the download package.

Typically, this is recommended:

```
<?php
echo $form->labelEx($model, 'field', 'label text');
echo $form->textField($model, 'field');
echo $form->error($model, 'field');
?>
```

If the model contains the data from database, it will show up when the view is loaded.
Your code in controller action could look like this:

```
// ...
$model = Model1::model()->findByPk($id); // $id has to be the primary key of the model you want to load
$this->render('viewfile', array(
    'model'=>$model, // this $model is then the same $model as in the view
));
```

Comment: Wait a second, the purpose that I have concern is to fill the value into textfield at the form. Not just being displayed. Thanks

Comment: With this form, you can both display database data and store user input into the model.